# ap_uniform_sampler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'high' in Ray Tune package for python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, hyperparameters, ray, hyperopt

I am trying to use the Ray [Tune](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune.html) package for hyperparameter tuning of a LSTM implemented using pure Tensorflow. I used the [hyperband](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune-schedulers.html) scheduler and [HyperOptSearch](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune-searchalg.html#hyperopt-search-tree-structured-parzen-estimators) algorithms for this and I am also using the trainable class method. When I try to run it I get the following error:

> TypeError: ap_uniform_sampler() missing 1 required positional
>   argument: 'high'

shown below is the stack trace:

FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.   from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters Process STDOUT and STDERR is being redirected to /tmp/ray/session_2018-12-19_09-43-46_5469/logs. Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:14332 to respond... Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:25158 to respond... Starting the Plasma object store with 3.220188364 GB memory using /dev/shm. Failed to start the UI, you may need to run 'pip install jupyter'.
== Status == Using HyperBand: num_stopped=0 total_brackets=0 Round #0: Resources requested: 0/4 CPUs, 0/0 GPUs Memory usage on this node:
3.7/8.1 GB

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/home/suleka/Documents/sales_prediction/auto_LSTM_try3.py", line 398, in <module>
    run_experiments(config, search_alg=algo, scheduler=hyperband)   
File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/tune.py", line 108, in run_experiments
    runner.step()   
File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/trial_runner.py", line 114, in step
    next_trial = self._get_next_trial()   
File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/trial_runner.py", line 254, in _get_next_trial
    self._update_trial_queue(blocking=wait_for_trial)   
File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/trial_runner.py", line 330, in _update_trial_queue
    trials = self._search_alg.next_trials()   
File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/suggest/suggestion.py", line 67, in next_trials
    for trial in self._trial_generator:   
File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/suggest/suggestion.py", line 88, in _generate_trials
    suggested_config = self._suggest(trial_id)   
File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/suggest/hyperopt.py", line 81, in _suggest
    self.rstate.randint(2**31 - 1))   
File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/tpe.py", line 835, in suggest
    = tpe_transform(domain, prior_weight, gamma)   
File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/tpe.py", line 816, in tpe_transform
    s_prior_weight   
File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/tpe.py", line 690, in build_posterior
    b_post = fn(*b_args, **dict(named_args)) 

TypeError: ap_uniform_sampler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'high'
```

My code is shown below:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import time

import ray
from ray.tune import grid_search, run_experiments, register_trainable, Trainable
from ray.tune.schedulers import HyperBandScheduler
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
# from ray.tune import sample_from

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import  pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
from ray.tune.suggest import HyperOptSearch
import argparse
from hyperopt import hp



num_steps = 14
lstm_size = 32
batch_size = 8
init_learning_rate = 0.01
learning_rate_decay = 0.99
init_epoch = 5  # 5
max_epoch = 60  # 100 or 50
hidden1_nodes = 30
hidden2_nodes = 15
hidden1_activation = tf.nn.tanh
hidden2_activation = tf.nn.tanh
lstm_activation = tf.nn.relu
input_size = 1
num_layers = 1
column_min_max = [[0, 11000], [1, 7]]
columns = ['Sales', 'DayOfWeek', 'SchoolHoliday', 'Promo']
features = len(columns)




def segmentation(data):

    seq = [price for tup in data[columns].values for price in tup]

    seq = np.array(seq)

    # split into items of features
    seq = [np.array(seq[i * features: (i + 1) * features])
           for i in range(len(seq) // features)]

    # split into groups of num_steps
    X = np.array([seq[i: i + num_steps] for i in range(len(seq) -  num_steps)])

    y = np.array([seq[i +  num_steps] for i in range(len(seq) -  num_steps)])

    # get only sales value
    y = [[y[i][0]] for i in range(len(y))]

    y = np.asarray(y)

    return X, y

def scale(data):

    for i in range (len(column_min_max)):
        data[columns[i]] = (data[columns[i]] - column_min_max[i][0]) / ((column_min_max[i][1]) - (column_min_max[i][0]))

    return data

def rescle(test_pred):

    prediction = [(pred * (column_min_max[0][1] - column_min_max[0][0])) + column_min_max[0][0] for pred in test_pred]

    return prediction


def pre_process():
    store_data = pd.read_csv('/home/suleka/salesPred/store2_1.csv')


    store_data = store_data.drop(store_data[(store_data.Open == 0) & (store_data.Sales == 0)].index)
    #
    # store_data = store_data.drop(store_data[(store_data.Open != 0) & (store_data.Sales == 0)].index)

    # ---for segmenting original data --------------------------------
    original_data = store_data.copy()

    ## train_size = int(len(store_data) * (1.0 - test_ratio))



    validation_len = len(store_data[(store_data.Month == 6) & (store_data.Year == 2015)].index)
    test_len = len(store_data[(store_data.Month == 7) & (store_data.Year == 2015)].index)
    train_size = int(len(store_data) -  (validation_len+test_len))

    train_data = store_data[:train_size]
    validation_data = store_data[(train_size-num_steps): validation_len+train_size]
    test_data = store_data[((validation_len+train_size) - num_steps): ]
    original_val_data = validation_data.copy()
    original_test_data = test_data.copy()


    # -------------- processing train data---------------------------------------
    scaled_train_data = scale(train_data)
    train_X, train_y = segmentation(scaled_train_data)

    # -------------- processing validation data---------------------------------------
    scaled_validation_data = scale(validation_data)
    val_X, val_y = segmentation(scaled_validation_data)


    # -------------- processing test data---------------------------------------
    scaled_test_data = scale(test_data)
    test_X, test_y = segmentation(scaled_test_data)

    # ----segmenting original validation data-----------------------------------------------
    nonescaled_val_X, nonescaled_val_y = segmentation(original_val_data)


    # ----segmenting original test data-----------------------------------------------
    nonescaled_test_X, nonescaled_test_y = segmentation(original_test_data)



    return train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y, val_X, val_y, nonescaled_test_y,nonescaled_val_y


def generate_batches(train_X, train_y, batch_size):
    num_batches = int(len(train_X)) // batch_size
    if batch_size * num_batches < len(train_X):
        num_batches += 1

    batch_indices = range(num_batches)
    for j in batch_indices:
        batch_X = train_X[j * batch_size: (j + 1) * batch_size]
        batch_y = train_y[j * batch_size: (j + 1) * batch_size]
        # assert set(map(len, batch_X)) == {num_steps}
        yield batch_X, batch_y



def setupRNN(inputs):

    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(lstm_size, state_is_tuple=True, activation=lstm_activation)

    val1, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

    val = tf.transpose(val1, [1, 0, 2])

    last = tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1, name="last_lstm_output")

    # hidden layer
    hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(last, units=hidden1_nodes, activation=hidden2_activation)
    hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, units=hidden2_nodes, activation=hidden1_activation)

    weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden2_nodes, input_size]))
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[input_size]))

    prediction = tf.matmul(hidden2, weight) + bias

    return prediction



class TrainMNIST(Trainable):
    """Example MNIST trainable."""

    def _setup(self, config):


        global num_steps, lstm_size, hidden2_nodes, hidden2_activation, hidden1_activation, hidden1_nodes, lstm_size, lstm_activation, init_learning_rate, init_epoch, max_epoch, learning_rate_decay

        self.timestep = 0


        self.train_X, self.train_y, self.test_X, self.test_y, self.val_X, self.val_y, self.nonescaled_test_y, self.nonescaled_val_y = pre_process()



        self.inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_steps, features], name="inputs")
        self.targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_size], name="targets")
        self.learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, None, name="learning_rate")



        num_steps = config["num_steps"]
        lstm_size = config["lstm_size"]
        hidden1_nodes = config["hidden1_nodes"]
        hidden2_nodes =  config["hidden2_nodees"]
        batch_size = config["batch_size"]
        init_learning_rate = getattr(config["learning_rate"])
        learning_rate_decay = getattr(config["learning_rate_decay"])
        max_epoch = getattr(config["max_epoch"])
        init_epoch = getattr(config["init_epoch"])


        self.prediction = setupRNN(self.inputs)

        with tf.name_scope('loss'):
            model_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(self.targets, self.prediction)

        with tf.name_scope('adam_optimizer'):
            train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(model_loss)

        self.train_step = train_step

        with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
            correct_prediction = tf.sqrt(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(self.prediction, self.targets))

        self.accuracy = correct_prediction


        self.sess = tf.Session()
        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        self.iterations = 0
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()

    def _train(self):

        learning_rates_to_use = [
            init_learning_rate * (
                    learning_rate_decay ** max(float(i + 1 - init_epoch), 0.0)
            ) for i in range(max_epoch)]


        for epoch_step in range(max_epoch):

            current_lr = learning_rates_to_use[epoch_step]

            i = 0

            for batch_X, batch_y in generate_batches(self.train_X, self.train_y, batch_size):
                train_data_feed = {
                    self.inputs: batch_X,
                    self.targets: batch_y,
                    self.learning_rate: 0.01,
                }

                self.sess.run(self.train_step, train_data_feed)



        val_data_feed = {
            self.inputs: self.val_X,
            self.targets: self.val_y,
            self.learning_rate: 0.0,
        }

        pred = self.sess.run(self.prediction, val_data_feed)

        pred_vals = rescle(pred)

        pred_vals = np.array(pred_vals)

        pred_vals = pred_vals.flatten()

        pred_vals = pred_vals.tolist()

        nonescaled_y = self.nonescaled_val_y.flatten()

        nonescaled_y = nonescaled_y.tolist()

        val_accuracy = sqrt(mean_squared_error(nonescaled_y, pred_vals))


})

        self.iterations += 1
        return {"RMSE_loss": val_accuracy}

    def _save(self, checkpoint_dir):
        return self.saver.save(
            self.sess, checkpoint_dir + "/save", global_step=self.iterations)

    def _restore(self, path):
        return self.saver.restore(self.sess, path)


# !!! Example of using the ray.tune Python API !!!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--smoke-test', action='store_true', help='Finish quickly for testing')
    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    ray.init(redirect_output=True)

    register_trainable("my_class", TrainMNIST)

    space = {
        'num_steps': hp.uniform('num_steps', 2, 14),
        'lstm_size': hp.uniform('lstm_size', [8,16,32,64,128]),
        'hidden1_nodes': hp.choice("hidden1_nodes", [4,8,16,32,64]),
        'hidden2_nodees': hp.choice("hidden2_nodees", [2,4,8,16,32]),
        'learning_rate': hp.choice("learning_rate", [0.01,0.1,0.5,0.05]),
        'learning_rate_decay': hp.choice("learning_rate_decay", [0.99,0.8,0.7]),
        'max_epoch': hp.choice("max_epoch", [60,50,100,120,200]),
        'init_epoch': hp.choice("init_epoch", [5,10,15,20]),
        'batch_size': hp.choice("batch_size", [5,8,16,30,31,64])
    }

    config = {
        "my_exp": {
            "run": "exp",
            "num_samples": 10 if args.smoke_test else 1000,
            "stop": {
                 'RMSE_loss': 400.00,
                 'time_total_s': 600,
            },
        }
    }


    algo = HyperOptSearch(space, max_concurrent=4, reward_attr="RMSE_loss")
    hyperband = HyperBandScheduler(
        time_attr="training_iteration", reward_attr="RMSE_loss", max_t=10)
    run_experiments(config, search_alg=algo, scheduler=hyperband)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like simple typographical error here:

```
'lstm_size': hp.uniform('lstm_size', [8,16,32,64,128]),
```

It seems that you wanted `lstm_size` to be chosen from the list supplied. In that case you need to use hp.choice here too, just like you used for all the other parameters below `'lstm_size'`.

```
'lstm_size': hp.choice('lstm_size', [8,16,32,64,128])
```